# AssetManager can't find file in assets directory

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Trying to load file from assets directory in order to use it as a config file. AssetManager can't locate it. Both config.global and config.properties are in the assets directory for the project. The config class is generated in the setUp() function which then calls readConfig to get started. Here's the code in the main file:

```
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    mLithium = (LithiumExtension) Trio.getInstance(new LithiumExtension(this))
            .getExtension();
    config = StorefrontConfig.getInstance();
    Resources resources = getActivity().getResources();
    AssetManager asM = resources.getAssets();
    InputStream in = asM.open("config.global");
    OutputStream out = asM.openFd("config.properties").createOutputStream();
    config.readConfig(in, out);
    setTestSettings();
}
```

And the code for Config:

```
public class Config {

private static Config instance;
public Properties prop;

static {
    instance = new Config();
}

private Config () {
    prop = new Properties();
}

public void readConfig(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {

    try {

        prop.load(in);
        in.close();

        prop.store(out, "yay");
        out.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to create properties");
        System.exit(3);
        Log.d("Config", "Failed to create properly initialized config class");
    }
}

public static Config getInstance() {

    if(instance == null)
        instance = new Config();
    return instance;
}

public String getProperty (String key) {
    return prop.getProperty(key);
}
}
```

When running, I get a `java.io.FileNotFoundException` for `config.global`. This is thrown at the `asM.open("config.global")` line of the code. Been stuck on this for awhile. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you get if you log the contents of `asM.list("")`?(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#list(java.lang.String)) Also, have you cleaned your project since adding the files to assets?

Comment: I've cleaned, refreshed, and rebuilt the entire project. Also, for some reason LogCat didn't output anything when I did Log.i(asM.list("")[0], null)

Comment: It's probably not finding the right assets. Try passing an activity context to the setup method like Tarsem suggests in comments below.

Comment: Note that you can't write to any of your assets; they are read-only

Comment: @j__m good Point ! but i think right now problem is that user2433924 is unable to get file from assets ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Receive Context** inside `setUp(Context c)` and use this for getting Assets

so try by
**Changing**

```
 AssetManager asM = resources.getAssets();
```

**to**

```
AssetManager asM = c.getAssets();
```

Comment: So, the setUp() code is actually in an Abstract class, so I can't call getAssets() directly.

Comment: Still can't find the file

Comment: @user2433924 are you getting same Exception ?

Comment: Yes, FileNotFoundException for config.global

Comment: verify your file ! double check your assets folder for  config.global file !

Comment: The file is definitely in the assets directory. There are 2 files there config.global for reading and config.properties for writing to.

Comment: instead of this getActivity(), try by using context !

Comment: I tried getActivity().getApplicationContext().getAssets(). No luck

Comment: receive  context in setUp(Context c), try by using them !